# How to install packages not available for RHEL4/CentOS4.9 using Yum?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, rhel

I'm running i386 RHEL4.5, I'm installing packages using Yum by manually setting its configuration as CentOS 4.9. I have to run a program, for which I cannot download the following packages: cryptsetup-luks-devel, libconfig-devel.

In /etc/yum.repos.d/RedHat-Base.repo, it has the following code:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/4.9/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1

[update]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/4.9/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
```

I tried changing the number 4.9 to 6.7 but then it searches in "http://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/i386/CentOS/RPMS/.." which does not exist.

How should I get about fixing this?

Comment: This is going to break your system if yum even allows it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get packages from `6.7`, this is the URL for it: http://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/i386/Packages/

Try changing your `.repo` file like this:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/i386/Packages/
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: I know that's the url, but I don't know how to make yum recognize it